# Localstack: which port to use for ES rest api

Tags: localstack

I am using docker to run Localstack and image `0.11.1`.
I turned on `es` service and exposed port `4566` - as according to the doc (https://github.com/localstack/localstack):

> Starting with version 0.11.0, all APIs are exposed via a single edge service, which is accessible on http://localhost:4566 by default

I could successfully use AWS CLI to list domain names and create ones:

```
aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 es list-domain-names
aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 es create-elasticsearch-domain --domain-name my-domain --elasticsearch-version 7.4
```

But when I tried to index document

```
curl -XPUT http://localhost:4566/my-domain/_doc/1 -d '{"hello": "World"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

it returned `{"status": "running"}` reponse to me and I saw the message in logs:

> INFO:localstack.services.edge: Unable to find forwarding rule for host "localhost:4566", path "/my-domain/_doc/1", target header "", auth header ""

Then I added port `4571` to exposed ports by configuring it in docker-compose.yml and tried the same, but using http://localhost:4571/my-domain/_doc/1 url this time to index document.

```
curl -XPUT http://localhost:4571/my-domain/_doc/1 -d '{"hello": "World"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

It worked.

I don't understand - according to the doc I should only use port `4566` but it does not work. 
Am I missing something?

---

My docker-compose.yml with both ports exposed:

```
...
localstack:
    container_name: "localstack"
    image: localstack/localstack:0.11.1
    privileged: true
    ports:
      - "4566:4566"
      - "4571:4571"
    environment:
      - SERVICES=es
      - START_WEB=0
      - LAMBDA_REMOTE_DOCKER=0
      - DATA_DIR=/tmp/localstack/data
...
```

Comment: did this ever get resolved? I'm having the same issue and banging my head against the proverbial wall

Comment: It seems the solution is to just not use the new edge service yet (as of v0.11.3). There are a lot of issues getting services to route to the correct place. For example https://github.com/localstack/localstack/issues/2329

Comment: My team is moving to localstack using 4566 for all services, need to sort out this issue asap. Anyone have any leads?

Comment: It seems like 4566 is used to access the AWS console, using the cli, but the services run on different ports, Elasticsearch Services being on port 4571.

Answer (score 1):

From [here](https://github.com/localstack/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/localstack/README.md), you can see this table:

| Parameter | Description | Default |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `service.edgePort` | Port number for Localstack edge service | `4566` |
| `service.esPort` | Port number for Localstack elasticsearch service | `4571` |